# How to use django TransactionMiddleware with MySQL database

Tags: mysql, django, http, transactions, request

In one of the projects I am working on, I am using the transactions explicitly as follows:

```
from django.db import transaction

@transaction.commit_on_succcess
def some_view(request):
    """ Renders some view
    """
```

I am using Django `1.5.5` and in the docs it says:

> The recommended way to handle transactions in Web requests is to tie them to the request and response phases via Django’s TransactionMiddleware.
>
> It works like this: When a request starts, Django starts a transaction. If the response is produced without problems, Django commits any pending transactions. If the view function produces an exception, Django rolls back any pending transactions.
>
> To activate this feature, just add the TransactionMiddleware middleware to your MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES setting:

I want to use the transactions on requests instead of tying them to a particular view that requires it but I am a little confused about how this'd work. Say I have a view as follows:

```
def some_view(request):
    """ Creates a user object.
    """

    context = {}
    first_name = request.POST['first_name']
    last_name = request.POST['last_name']
    email = request.POST['email']

    try:
        create_user(first_name, last_name, email)
        context['success'] = 'User %s was added to the database.' % (first_name)
    except IntegrityError, err:
        context['failure'] = 'An error occurred while adding user to the database: %s' % (str(err))
    except Exception, err:
        context['failure'] = '%s' % (str(err))

   return json_response(context)
```

In the above view we are handling the exceptions and returning a response and in the docs it states:

> If the response is produced without problems, Django commits any pending transactions.

**Q**: Will the transactions be committed in the above mentioned view even if it raises an exception ?

What if we want to create multiple objects in a single request and only want to rollback a single entry that raises an exception but commit all other ? So for example, we read a data from the file and for each row we want to create a user object, we want all the users to be inserted into the database except for the ones that raise an error:

```
def some_view(request):
    """ Creates a user object.
    """

    context = {}
    data = # Read from file

    for row in data:
        first_name, last_name, email = row.split(",")

        try:
            create_user(first_name, last_name, email)
            context['success'] = 'User %s was added to the database.' % (first_name)
        except IntegrityError, err:
            context['failure'] = 'An error occurred while adding user to the database: %s' % (str(err))
        except Exception, err:
            context['failure'] = '%s' % (str(err))

   return json_response(context)
```

**Q**: How would the transactions work in this case ? Is it better to explicitly use transactions here ?

**Update**:

In my case I am using an Inherited model class. Example:

```
class BaseUser(models.Model)
   first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   email = models.EmailField(max_length=100, unique=True)


class UserA(BaseUser):
   phone = models.BigIntegerField()
   type = models.CharField(max_length=32)
```

So in case I am trying to create a `UserA` type object using the above view and it raises an exception, The `BaseUSer` object is created with the given data but `UserA` type object is not. So, what I am trying to do is to either create the `TypeA` object or do not commit any changes. Currently I am using transactions manually (as follows) and it seem to work fine, It's just that I want to switch to using transactions on HTTP requests instead.

```
from django.db import transaction


transaction.commit_on_success()
def some_view(request):
    """ Creates a user object.
    """

    context = {}
    data = # Read from file

    for row in data:
        first_name, last_name, email = row.split(",")

        try:
            sid = transaction.savepoint()
            create_user(first_name, last_name, email)
            context['success'] = 'User %s was added to the database.' % (first_name)
            transaction.savepoint_commit()
        except IntegrityError, err:
            context['failure'] = 'An error occurred while adding user to the database: %s' % (str(err))
            transaction.savepoint_rollback()
        except Exception, err:
            transaction.savepoint_rollback()
            context['failure'] = '%s' % (str(err))

   return json_response(context)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need transactions at all here. If an IntegrityError is raised, that means the database update couldn't even be done, so there is nothing to roll back.

Transactions are useful if you want to roll back *all* the updates if a single one fails.

Comment: Well in my case, The `user` model class uses inheritance, So when I try to create multiple objects using invalid data for a field in the parent class, the child class object is created but the parent class is not .. why is that so ?

Comment: you can see the update in my question to get a better understanding of my problem, Thanks.